# NSFetchedResultsController overwriting last cell on insert

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an application that uses an `NSFetchedResultsController` attached to a `UITableView`.

I'm encountering a very odd problem, in that when an insert is done into the database with a new item that should appear at the bottom of the table, the cell for the last item is replaced with the newly inserted item - so the screen now shows the item I just inserted, but the one just before that is lost. Further inserts exhibit the same behavior, the table does not grow and the last item is replaced with any new items.

When the app is re-started the full table of data appears as it should (in other words the overwritten cell still has data in the database).  It seems like the fetched results controller loses track of where the new item should go.

An example of before and after:

[image: Before]

[image: After]

ADDITION:

The existing code for `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:`

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    UITableView *fetchTableView = [self tableViewForFetchedResultsController:controller];
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [fetchTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
               break;
///....
    }
```

Comment: It depends on how you update the table, presumably in the fetchd results controller delegate callback. Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

This phenomenon seems to indicate that in the offending update code you are updating the last cell, rather than inserting one.

Use
`insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` rather than
`reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using the wrong parameter in your method :

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
```

Be careful to use the `newIndexPath` parameter, not `indexPath`, when inserting a row :

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```